# Proving line is perpendicular using partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Consider a smooth surface given by the function $z = f(x,y)$, such that the partial
derivatives of $f(x,y)$ exist. Suppose $Q$ is a point that does not lie on the surface,
and $P$ is the nearest point on the surface to $Q$. Show that the line through $P$ and
$Q$ is perpendicular to the surface at $P$.

Comment: "...through $\;P,\,Q\;$ is perpendicular" ...perpendicular **to what**?

Answer (score 0):

At the point $P(x_p,y_p,z_p)$; the tangent plane to the surface $z=f(x,y)$ has following cartesian equation :

$$z-z_p=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_p,y_p)(x-x_p)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_p,y_p)(y-y_p)$$

thus the normal vector is $$\vec{PQ}=\lambda (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_p,y_p),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_p,y_p),-1)$$

Comment: How do you justify that the normal to the tangent plane is $\;\vec{PQ}\;$ ? I mean, how does $\;Q\;$ enters there?